# mysql pagination left join vs. union LIMIT

Tags: mysql, pagination, left-join, limit, union

I have a table 'gems' where posts are stored (e.g. blog) . Replies to the post are also stored in the same table with a field storing the key of the parent post. Each post can have files attached.

I need to get a list of posts with associated replies and attached files.
'gems' therefore has multiple LEFT JOINS to it - one to itself and one to 'gemdetail' with the filenames. This query works:

```
SELECT g.gemid as gemidx, g.title, gemdetail.filename, r.gemid as rgemid, r.title, r.filename
FROM (SELECT * FROM gems WHERE gems.grade = '7' LIMIT 0, 10) g 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.title, x.gemid, x.replygemid, y.filename from gems x 
    LEFT JOIN gemdetail y ON x.gemid = y.gemid ) r ON g.gemid = r.replygemid 
LEFT JOIN gemdetail ON g.gemid = gemdetail.gemid
```

However, if I have 20 replies and 10 files for each post, the number of returned records is 200 per post. The LIMIT clause works, but this is still a lot of records. Plus dealing with the recordset is a bear.

I rewrote the query to use a UNION which will return only 40 records per post (instead of 200). 
The UNION has 4 parts - 1) return the first 10 records (LIMIT) 2) get filenames for the posts  3) get replies 4) get filenames for replies

The UNION query below works except that I cannot LIMIT the number of returned records for any other than the first part of the UNION. I can put LIMIT statements into each part of the UNION, but this is not correct (I want to limit files and replies to be in the set of the LIMITed 10 posts). When I try to use a WHERE gemid IN (SELECT gemid from gems....) clause for any of the UNIONS I get the mySQL subquery limit error.

```
SELECT g.gemid as gemidx, g.title, NULL as filename, NULL as rgemid, 'ag' as flag 
FROM (SELECT * FROM gems WHERE ISNULL(gems.replygemid) AND gems.grade = '7' LIMIT 0, 10) g
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM gems) r ON g.gemid = r.replygemid  

UNION SELECT g.gemid as gemidx, g.title, gemdetail.filename as filename, NULL as rgemid, 'bf' as flag 
FROM (SELECT * FROM gems WHERE ISNULL(gems.replygemid) AND gems.grade = '7') g 
INNER JOIN gemdetail ON g.gemid = gemdetail.gemid

UNION SELECT g.replygemid as gemidx, g.title, NULL as filename, g.gemid as rgemid, 'cr' as flag 
FROM (SELECT * FROM gems WHERE NOT ISNULL(gems.replygemid) AND gems.grade = '7') g 

UNION SELECT g.replygemid as gemidx, g.title, gemdetail.filename as filename, g.gemid as rgemid, 'df' as flag 
FROM (SELECT * FROM gems WHERE NOT ISNULL(gems.replygemid) AND gems.grade = '7') g 
INNER JOIN gemdetail ON g.gemid = gemdetail.gemid 

ORDER BY gemidx desc, rgemid, flag
```

Please help. Is there a way to effeciently select (for pagination sake) only 10 posts and all its associated replies & files? Thanks for taking the time in reading this. I have spent 2 days on this and am at my LIMIT (lousy pun intended...).

Comment: You can probably add a sequence number dynamically to each response, starting at 0 for each posts first response, and then just select those where the sequence number is less than X.

Comment: Interesting idea... Presuming you are referring to the UNION, I still don't see how I SELECT responses only from the posts limited in the first part of the UNION?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a play around, but this code is a bit nasty so you might not want to use it. This is ignoring files for now though. Note that I got something similar to work on a table of mine and then derived this from it, but I have not tested this directly so there may be typos in it.

```
SELECT gems.gemid as gemidx, gems.title, r.gemid as rgemid, r.title, r.filename
FROM gems
INNER JOIN (SELECT gems.*, @runningtotal:=@runningtotal+1 AS CurrentTotal
FROM (SELECT @runningtotal := 0)Deriv1, gems 
ORDER BY replygemid) r
INNER JOIN (SELECT replygemid, MIN(CurrentTotal) AS MinTotal
FROM (SELECT replygemid, @runningtotal:=@runningtotal+1 AS CurrentTotal
FROM (SELECT @runningtotal := 0)Deriv1, gems 
ORDER BY replygemid) Deriv2
GROUP BY replygemid) Deriv5
ON Deriv4.replygemid = Deriv5.replygemid 
AND Deriv4.CurrentTotal < Deriv5.MinTotal + 10
WHERE gems.grade = '7'
```

What this is doing is using a subselect to add a sequence number to the replies (ordered by the parent). It uses this subselect twice, once to get the min sequence number for a group and then again to bring back all the rowdetails with the sequence number. This is then JOINed to get those where the sequence number is one of the first 10 for that gem.

While I prefer to keep things within a single piece of SQL I think this is getting to the stage where it will be too slow to be worthwhile.

It might be possible to put the file details in using GROUP_CONCAT to add them all for a gem reply and then in your code dispose of the ones you are not interested in (ie, over 10)

Sorry I can't come up with anything more useful

Comment: I hadn't considered using dynamic vars to track records. It is gnarly. The first sql query I posted above does actually limit the records correctly, so I don't think this would be an advantage over it. The recordset is a pain to work with (vs. the cleanness of the UNION) but at least it works. I've decided to continue with it and hope performance isn't an issue. Thanks for your suggestion.